# how to access request in tastypie Resource?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

```
#api.py

class MyResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Model.objects.all()
```

This would get an api with all objects of that Model. I use an app called django -vote to get only the voted objects of a Model.
in this way `queryset = Model.votes.all(request.user.id)` . But how to access request in a Resource class?

Answer (score 1):

You can override [get_object_list](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook.html#per-request-alterations-to-the-queryset) method of `ModelResource`.

```
class MyResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Model.objects.all()

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        qs = super(MyResource, self).get_object_list(request)
        return qs.filter(user=request.user)
```

Comment: But I need to access Model.votes.all( request.id ) instead, which is a queryset too.